# How do I install the drivers for my Canon PC-D320 printer?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, canon

I've got a printer, which is not listed in the list of drivers for Ubuntu.

The printers name is: `Canon PC-D320`

So how do I install the drivers? Where can I find them?

Comment: Go to canon website. Maybe there you can get the driver for the required platform.

Comment: The problem is that canon doesn't provide drivers for other systems than Windows. (Windows 98-8)

Comment: try this ppa:https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon

Comment: So I just had a look on this site: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon but I did not know, how to use the driver now (I am new on Linux). So could you help me a bit? :) I already tiped in that in my terminal: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon"

Answer (score 0):

Need to use ***Canon printer driver daily*** [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk) in higher versions from Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cndrvcups-common cnijfilter-common scangearmp-common
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in Trusty