# Where to get the linuxdrivers for my printer Canon PC-D320?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have got a **Canon PC-D320** and I would like to print something.
But unfortunatly, that drivers aren't listed in the list of drivers in Ubuntu.

So I was searching on the internet for that, but I dind't find something.

So if anyone could get me a link to download and a description how to install the drivers, it would be really nice. I'm a beginner on Linux, but I want to get more practised.

Thanks a lot!

Jenne

Comment: I don't know anything about this particular printer. Does it connect via USB, wired network via your router, or WIFI? Have you tried installing via cups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the drivers for my Canon PC-D320 printer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310589/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-my-canon-pc-d320-printer)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Canon Advanced Printing Technology (CAPT). It's an official closed-source printer driver. [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver) can help you through the installation and configuration.

Comment: The downloadlink isn't avaivable anymore...

Comment: [This](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100459602.html) is the link to download, up-to-date (last update 03-Jun-2013). Unfortunately the *.deb* package link is not available too.

Comment: Can you show me, how to get this working? Would be really nice. I'm new on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same printer myself and solved it this way on Ubuntu 14.04:

## Compile and install driver

There is an [open-source driver for canon carps printers](https://github.com/ondrej-zary/carps-cups) on github. You'll have to compile it yourself and configure some stuff.

First, download a zip of the source code: https://github.com/ondrej-zary/carps-cups/archive/master.zip

Extract the .zip file, open a terminal and go to the extracted folder. To make sure you are in the correct folder, type ls and you should see a similar output:

```
~/Downloads/carps-cups-master$ ls
carps-decode    carps.h    Makefile       rastertocarps.c  test-encode.sh
carps-decode.c  carps.txt  ppd            README.md
carps.drv       LICENSE    rastertocarps  test-decode.sh
```

install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev cups-ppdc
```

compile and install the packages:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now, when you try to add the printer via the "printers" dialog, it should automatically detect the correct driver. However, to get the PC-D320 working perfectly, we still have to change some configuration.

## PC-D320 specific configuration

Without this configuration, the printer only prints the first print job, and you have to restart the printer to print a second print job.

```
sudo nano /etc/cups/cups-files.conf
```

and change `#FileDevice No` to `FileDevice Yes`. Restart cups:

```
sudo service cups restart
```

Add the printer via the "printers" dialog, but change the `uri` to `file:///dev/usb/lpX` where `X` depends on your system. In my case it was `file:///dev/usb/lp1` you can check what lpX the printer is by running

```
udevadm info -a --name=/dev/usb/lpX
```