# Installing Canon PIXMA MX395 printer drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, pixma

How can I get Ubuntu drivers for *Canon PIXMA MX395* Printer & Fax ?

I'm lost here. I've tired a few things, but nothing is working. I need help !

Answer (score 1):

The repo from Michael Gruz is outdated. **[Canon Asia](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/?personal) provides the Linux drivers**.... I don't understand why Canon Europe nor Canone USA does it, but this is the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to CANON MX395 for UBUNTU 12.04 connected via USB

1. Download from the canon website the .deb.tar.gz drivers listed below:

   ```
   cnijfilter-common_3.90-1_i386.deb
   cnijfilter-mx390series_3.90-1_i386.deb
   scangearmp-common_2.10-1_i386.deb
   scangearmp-mx390series_2.10-1_i386.deb
   ```

   From: http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MX_series/MX395.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Linux
2. Extract them by right clicking on them and "selecting open with archive manager".
3. In a terminal, `cd` into the folder where you put them and type this line after line:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-common_3.90-1_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-mx390series_3.90-1_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-common_2.10-1_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-mx390series_2.10-1_i386.deb
   sudo system-config-printer
   ```
4. Open a browser and go to

   localhost:631 → administration → add printer → Local Printers: 
   (select closest to this) USB Printer #1 with status readback for Canon IJ (Canon MX390 series...
5. Try printing something with printer on, connect via USB 
   wait 3 minutes: the printer takes that long to initiate.

See if this works.

Answer (score 0):

It Turns out Canon USA doesn't provide ANY `Linux drivers` at all. So, your options are to find a driver through TurboPrint etc. I stumbled upon this particular driver here:

Canon's Australia site:

http://support-au.canon.com.au/P/search?model=PIXMA%20MX396&filter=0&menu=Download

Answer (score 0):

Cannon Printer drivers can be installed by **ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk** [Repository](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk)

Installation guide is in this [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/378229/164718) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions here helped me set up our MX850 even though it talks about a different model

http://blog.kenweiner.com/2011/04/using-canon-pixma-mx882-all-in-one-with.html