# Printing queue stuck with Canon Pixma 2555S on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon

I've tried a lot of things without success to have my printer working. summarizing:
Once upon a time (3 months ago), my printer, a Canon Pixma MG2555S worked alright with Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. both printing and scanning.
I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 ant I needed quite some search to get my printer working again. A week later it didn't work anymore and no solution found. I asked some help on french speaking forums with no more hints than tutorials or commands I had already tried, no better result.

So I switched back to Ubuntu 18.04, being unhappy about 20.04 not only because of printing mess.
And I can't have my printer working now, even on 18.04, yay!

So here is what I've tried up till now, with no results:

- adding repository  `add-apt-repository -ry ppa:michael-gruz/canon` upgrading and adding the precise driver Pixma MG2555S
- purging cups and installing cups again
- removing ippusbxd

I believe the result of following commands can start for a diagnosis:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 25a7:fa10  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04a9:176d Canon, Inc. PIXMA MG2550
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


 lpinfo -v
network beh
file cups-brf:/
network ipps
network ipp
network https
network socket
network lpd
network http


lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
matériel pour MG2500 : usb://Canon/MG2500%20series?serial=2D9A38&interface=1
MG2500 accepte des requêtes depuis jeu. 08 avr    lpstat -o
MG2500-12               franswa           1024   jeu. 08 avril 2021 14:41:05 CESTil 2021 14:41:05 CEST
printer MG2500 now printing MG2500-12.  enabled since jeu. 08 avril 2021 14:41:05 CEST
    Sending data to printer.
MG2500-12               franswa           1024   jeu. 08 avril 2021 14:41:05 CEST
```

translation from 2 lines in French is
device for MG2500 : usb://Canon/MG2500%20series?serial=2D9A38&interface=1
MG2500 accepting requests since thursday April 8 ...

what could help ?
Best regards

Comment: There are 5 answers in [this question(https://askubuntu.com/questions/378889/installing-canon-pixma-mx395-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu) which might help. Did you look through them?

Comment: Yes I did try these already. Besides, note the solutions provided on that link are all quite out of date : 2014 for the most recent ones. Is there anything to check regarding the printin stuck at 21% ?